# Reset component state in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, reset

I want to reset the state of only certain (not all) states.
On the click of a button, values of `present_count`, `total_count`, `present` and `total` should be set to their initial state (0). While the state of `subjects` and `text` should remain intact.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      subjects: [],
      text: "",
      present_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      total_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      present: 0,
      total: 0
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I am using `AsyncStorage` to save the modified state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to override the current state values and then use the current state value of `text`, `subjects`:

```
// default state 
const defaultState = {
  subjects: [],
  text: "",
  present_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  total_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  present: 0,
  total: 0
}

// component constructor.
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...defaultState };
}

// click event handler    
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    ...defaultState,
    subjects: this.state.subjects,
    text: this.state.text
  });
}
```

Comment: In ```this.state = defaultState;``` shouldn't I make a shallow copy of defaultState using spread operator, otherwise it will become refernced and changing one's state will change the state of other too.

Comment: Nothing's happening on button click. I am using AsyncStorage to save the modified state in other functions, should I implement that here too? If yes! Then how?

Comment: for the first comment yes, spread operator should be used, I will update my answer. For the second comment, not sure why its not updating in your code base.

Comment: It is working. It's just that I need to kill the app and then reopen it to view changed state. Any way to reload the state without killing the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object store your state your initial state of states you want to reset, like this:

```
const initState = {
   total: 0,
   present: 0,
   present_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   total_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}
```

and then you can

```
this.setState({
   ...initialState
})
```

on your button onClick

Hope that help. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Using the spread operator would likely be useful here.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.defaultState = {
      present_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      total_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      present: 0,
      total: 0
    }
    this.state = { 
      subjects: [],
      text: "",
      ...defaultState,
    }
}
.
.
.
onClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    ...this.defaultState, // This will only pass in values from your defaultState and leave the others (subjects & text) alone
  });
}
```